# How to preserve Object data without passing between activities within Android?

Tags: android, object, parcelable

Actually,my application flow is like this Home->A->B->Info(form data)->D->Final page.From final page if I press on one button it again navigates back to A page and start the flow from onwards.If I comes to info page I should display the earliear data.Right now my approach is passing parcelable object within all acitivities from A->B->Info->D->Final.If suppose want to use Preferences, doesn't supports the parcelable object and don't want to put each string of object individually within preferences becaus I had more than 10 items within object.Is there any better approach without passing bundle between actvities.

BR,
Developer.

Answer (score 2):

you can create `Global class` and `declare Static` variables and use them in anyware in the application.
Example:

```
public class global_variable {
    public static  String sample ;
}
```

where you want to use ;

```
global_variable.sample = "your value";
```

Comment: Am I correct in assuming that static class will consumes more memory than parcelable object?

Comment: Honestly say i dont know sorry for that but why u worry about memory ?

Comment: Is that a serious cuestion "why u worry about memory?" outofmemoryerror is very common in mobile, everybody worries about memory.

Answer (score 0):

You could use any number of technologies to parse your data object into a string and reassemble again. Then you could store the string in preferences.

Take a look at gson to convert objects to json http://code.google.com/p/google-gson/
Or you could google xstream to convert to xml

Answer (score -1):

If you create a class representing your 'object' with appropriate setters/getters and let that class implement `Parceable` and then pass that class between `Activites` as a `Parceable` in a `Bundle`, would that be bad?

If that would be bad (e.g. if the amount of object data is *very* big or they are somehow not `Parceable` in principle) and you only have one meaningful instance of a class at a time you can make that class a singleton or  keep it within your `Application` object.